# Elasticsearch term query to number token

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to explain some weird behavior of term query to Elasticsearch database which contains number part in the string. Query is pretty simple:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "address.street": "8 kvetna"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that term **8 kvetna** returns empty result. I tried to _analyze it ad it make regular tokens like 8, k, kv, kve .... Also I am pretty sure there is a value 8 kvetna in database.
Here is the mapping for the field:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "refresh_interval": "1m",
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "autocomplete_filter": {
                        "type": "edge_ngram",
                        "min_gram": "1",
                        "max_gram": "20"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "asciifolding",
                            "autocomplete_filter"
                        ],
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard"
                    }
                    "default": {
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "asciifolding"
                        ],
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "_all": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
                "address": {
                    "properties": {
                        "city": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                        },
                        "street": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "autocomplete"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What caused this weird result? I don't understand it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great start so far! Your only issue is that you're using a `term` query, while you should use a `match` one. A `term` query will try to do an exact match for `8 kvetna` and that's not what you want. The following query will work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {                               <--- change this
            "address.street": "8 kvetna"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```